# Whats the default in IE9 for the css attribute height for an img tag

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-9

I use Twitter Bootstrap for my website but also AD Gallery as Image Gallery (http://coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery/).

I have several tabs made with bootstrap on my page, the gallery is on the second tab. I found out, that there is a problem with IE 9 (it works in Firefox and Chrome) to not show the images in the gallery.

I debugged this and found out that this is due to a css command in the Bootstrap reset:

```
img {
    height: auto;
}
```

If I remove this line, everything works fine also in IE9.

I don't want to remove this line completely but override it in my own CSS for this specific gallery div. The funny thing is, that "auto" is already the default value for this attribute.

So how can I reset it to "not set" as it is, if I comment out this line in Bootstrap?

Comment: why you don't want to remove it?

Comment: Perhaps it can be helpful in other places of the website. I think it is in the Bootstrap css for some reason. :-)

Comment: `height: auto` is the default...

Comment: "I found out, that there is a problem with IE 9" - That is the default.

Comment: When you remove this instruction, is there another value set by Bootstrap? (I guess no, `img` hasn't much specificity). What are the other instructions applied (*does it float?* ^^ etc) that could cause a problem here and not elsewhere?

Comment: @zottto hi zotto i'm motto. the fate brings us together with the same problem and similiar nicknames. what a crazy world, you can check my question from here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179679/how-to-override-css-img-properties

could you found any solutions for that ?

Comment: @FelipeAls you can take a look to my questions with working example on same issue:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179679/how-to-override-css-img-properties

Comment: @GionaF the reason of it can be seen here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179679/how-to-override-css-img-properties

Answer (score 0):

Checking the IE9 default stylesheet confirms img height is not set to anything, which to me implies auto so this is strange.

Does `height:inherit` work? Edit: No it does not.

Comment: it will inherit the value from the parent element http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that in the original question: I already tried this too but with no success.

Comment: Have you checked to make absolutely certain that you didn't include any css before you included the bootstrap? Also have you used Developer Tools to look closely at overridden styles?

Comment: @SyntaxError you can check my question with a working example on this issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179679/how-to-override-css-img-properties