# How to override css img properties?

Tags: css, html, overriding

I have noticed weird conflict between [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) (2.2.1) and [ad-gallery](http://coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery/) in Internet Explorer.

Turns out this lines in bootstrap.min.css causing a problem and images don't show up:

```
img{max-width:100%;width:auto\9;height:auto;vertical-align:middle;border:0;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;}
```

when i remove these two everything works normally:

```
width:auto\9;height:auto;
```

But instead of removing those i am trying to override those properties but none of this worked so far:

```
.ad-gallery img{width:default;height:default;}
.ad-gallery img{width:none;height:none;}
.ad-gallery img{width:auto;height:auto;}
```

How to override these properties ?

btw. there isn't any problems with google chrome and mozilla firefox.
You can check the example with original bootstrap min css file from [here](http://bedavaemlaksitesi.com/adgallery-bootstrap-conflict/ilan-detay.html), which is not working.

Here is the working example with modified bootstrap-modified.min.css from [here](http://bedavaemlaksitesi.com/adgallery-bootstrap-conflict/ilan-detay-2.html).

Comment: What are you trying to do with the images in `.ad-gallery` ?? Because by default they will be auto width & height based on the bootstrap CSS - so I'm confused to what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: In which version of IE are you seeing this? I tried this in IE9 and it seems to work. http://jsfiddle.net/ty6aB/5/

Comment: @Andy added a working and non-working version with IE. Did you understand the question ?

Comment: @juan.facorro it's not working, check the examples below my question.

Comment: Have you tried using the '!important' tag? http://www.design3edge.com/2009/12/08/important-tag-css/

Comment: @AndrewPope yes it didn't worked also i didn't see any point of using that. what exactly i should use ? auto didn't work. none didn't too.

Comment: @motto I meant it's working for me when I define the specific `.ad-gallery img` class. Is it not working for you when you open this demo? http://jsfiddle.net/ty6aB/5/

Comment: @juan.facorro problem is not with jsfiddle and no it's not working. did you read the updated question ? try example links with ie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As observed, the parent **div** (which has a class **ad-image**) of the **img** has the following in-line styles:

```
    left: 230px;
    top: 160px;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
```

This is actually the cause why your **img** also has the width and height of zero.

Oh, I know you didn't place those styles because it has a different value in Chrome (or in FF). So, where is the problem coming? Yeah, right, it is from the JavaScript.

I checked the plugin that you used **jquery.ad-gallery.js** and made some debugging.

I found out that the plugin is computing the dimension and position of the **ad-image** container using the dimension of the **img**. The dimension of the img is acquired using the dimension of the preloaded (cached) image.

The problem with IE is that it's returning back zero-value dimensions for the image causing its parent, which height and width are computed using it, to also have zero-value dimensions.

Try to check if you can solve this JS issue. I believe that once this is solved, your issue will also be solved without additional CSS styles.

As a **work-around**, add the following rule to your css:

```
    .ad-image {
        left: 0 !important;
        top: 0 !important;
        width: inherit !important;
        height: inherit !important;
    }
```

Comment: turns out that work-around works. Great analyze, great answer.

Answer (score 1):

JS

```
$(function(){
    var galleries = $('.ad-gallery').adGallery({
        effect: ($.browser.msie) ? 'none' : 'slide-hori',
        callbacks: {
            afterImageVisible: function() {
                if ($.browser.msie) {
                    var img = this.current_image.find('img');
                    var size = this._getContainedImageSize(img.width(), img.height());
                    img.width(size.width).height(size.height);
                    img.css('margin-left', (this.current_image.width() - img.width()) / 2);
                    img.css('margin-top', (this.current_image.height() - img.height()) / 2);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

CSS

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style>
    .ad-gallery .ad-image {
        left: 0 !important;
        top: 0 !important;
        width: inherit !important;
        height: inherit !important;
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Is a problem with selector hierarchy with the DOM, I believe. Try:

```
.ad-gallery img{width:auto!important;}
```

Comment: I have added a css line as you stated but this is not a solution too.

http://bedavaemlaksitesi.com/adgallery-bootstrap-conflict/ilan-detay-3.html

Comment: please check the lines between style tags in source code of the web-page.